# Problemas al realizar una consulta dinamica

Tags: vb.net

Este es mi codigo y quiero realizar dinamicamente una consulta a mi base de datos sin tener que poner valores a los parametros departamento y universidad ya que esos datos los obtengo de un dropdownlist, como podria hacer en ese caso estoy trabajando en visual studio

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable Tabla;
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //SqlConnection conexionSQL = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\bdprueba; Initial Catalog=BDUbicaciones;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlConnection conexionSQL = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.1.107;Initial Catalog=GestionVoluntarios;User ID=st;Password=juli12");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select id,Latitud,Longitud,Nombres,Apellidos,Direccion,(select Nombre from dbo.tbwbDepartamento  where id=Departamento)Departamento,Telefono,Correo from tbwbVoluntario where  (status=1) and Departamento ='19' and Universidad ='15' and latitud <>'0' and longitud <>'0'";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conexionSQL;
                conexionSQL.Open();

                Tabla = new DataTable();
                Tabla.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                Repeater1.DataSource = Tabla;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                conexionSQL.Close();
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si no te estoy entendiendo mal, tendrás dos desplegables en tu aplicación, uno para departamentos y otro para universidades. Suponiendo que estos fuesen dropDepartamentos y dropUniversidades, la consulta quedaría algo así:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select id,Latitud,Longitud,Nombres,Apellidos,Direccion,(select Nombre from dbo.tbwbDepartamento  where id=Departamento)Departamento,Telefono,Correo from tbwbVoluntario where  (status=1) and Departamento ='" + dropDepartamentos.SelectedValue + "' and Universidad ='" + dropUniversidades.SelectedValue + "' and latitud <>'0' and longitud <>'0'";
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo.